# Understand router Ip address and Mac address, Switch Mac address

Tags: switching, ip-address, mac-address, layer2, layer3

**Scenario:1**

Suppose external Router *R1* has interface **a** connected with interface **b** of the  site  Router *R2.* And Router *R1* using IP address 80.0.0.0/8 for **a.** Router R2 has 4 subnets 80.0.0.0/10, 80.64.0.0/10, 80.128.0.0/10, 80.192.0.0/10.
[image]
My first question is router R1 with interface **a** and router R2 interface **b**  has same ip address 80.0.0.0/8 or interface **a** using 80.0.0.0/8 and interface **b** using 80.0.0.0/10?

My second question is router R2's interface **c** has ip address 80.0.0.0/10?or any of the IP address of the block 80.0.0.0/10 for example 80.0.0.1/10?

**Scenario:2**

Suppose a host A, host B, router connected to 3 different ports of switch.Suppose host A has interface M and Mac address **aaaa** connected to switch port of N.
[image]

My question is switch port interface N and host interface M could share same Mac address or  switch has 3 different Mac  address for it's interface N, P, Q?

Comment: *Router R1 using IP address 80.0.0.0/8* isn't possible since that address has all host bits set to zero. It's the network prefix and unusable as an actual interface address. *Router R2 has 4 subnets 80.0.0.0/10, 80.64.0.0/10, 80.128.0.0/10, 80.192.0.0/10* is also not possible as these subnets all overlap with 80.0.0.0/8.

Comment: @Zac67  If A wants to send frame to B. My question is layer2 frame from A to switch reached by port number Or Mac address? A using destination Mac of B, but A reached to switch by using port number?

Comment: The switch receives A's frame (on port N, learns/updates A's MAC association), looks up B's MAC in its SAT/CAM, sees the association with port Q and forwards the frame out of that port.

Comment: @Zac67 SAT/CAM full form?

Comment: *Source address table* and *content-addressable memory* (table).

Comment: @Zac67 suppose router R1 has interface a has IP address 81.0.0.1 and IP address of interface b of R2 could be any belongs to any of 4 subnets. I mean interface b has IP address could be 80.0.0.1 or 80.64.0.2 or 80.128.0.2 or 80.192.0.5?

Comment: R1's port a and R2's port b are required to share a common subnet in order to communicate. 81.0.0.1/24 and 81.0.0.2/24 would work. OTOH, 81.0.0.1/7, 80.0.0.1/7, 80.64.0.2/7, 80.128.0.2/7, and/or 80.192.0.5/7 would also work. You might want to read up on what the subnet mask is about.

Comment: @Zac67 when 80.0.0.1/7, 80.64.0.2/7, 80.128.0.2/7, and/or 80.192.0.5/7 use for then it could not be overlapped with 80.0.0.1/10, 80.64.0.2/10, 80.128.0.2/10,  80.192.0.5/10 c, e, g, i interface, if I design?

Comment: Yes, they would overlap - I was referring to those two interfaces only. All the /10 subnets are part of 80.0.0.1/7. You should really read up on [basic subnetting](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers).

Comment: @Zac67 if A connected by Ethernet to switch then both interface M and N has unique Mac address?

Comment: A switch doesn't use MAC addresses on its interfaces, a switch is transparent on layer 2. Routers and hosts use MAC addresses. And all of them must be unique.

Comment: @Zac67 but switch ports also transparent, why they use ports?

Comment: @Zac67 what do you mean by Mac address transparent on layer 2?

Comment: @Zac67 “Transparent” means that when you connect a switch to an Ethernet system, no changes are made in the Ethernet frames that are bridged

Comment: @Zac67 router every interface has unique routing table?

Comment: Yes, each router has its own routing table and makes its own forwarding decision.

Comment: @Zac67 all interface of one router has one routing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first question is router R1 with interface a and router R2 interface b has same ip address 80.0.0.0/8 or interface a using 80.0.0.0/8 and interface b using 80.0.0.0/10?

80.0.0.0 is a unique address, regardless of the subnet mask.  So two devices cannot have that same address.  Remember though that 80.0.0.0 is not a valid host address with a mask of /8 (or /10).  You could use 80.0.0.1

Interfaces a and b can be on any unique subnet.  They don't have to be part of the 80.0.0.0/8 subnet.

The routing table of R1 should have a route to 80.0.0.0/8, with the next hop of interface b on R2.

> My second question is router R2's interface c has ip address 80.0.0.0/10?or any of the IP address of the block 80.0.0.0/10 for example 80.0.0.1/10?

Since 80.0.0.0/10 is not a valid host address, the next available address in that subnet is 80.0.0.1

> My question is switch port interface N and host interface M could share same Mac address or switch has 3 different Mac address for it's interface N, P, Q?

The switch's interfaces don't have MAC addresses. Another (old) name for a switch is a *transparent bridge*. It transparently forwards frames based on its MAC forwarding table.   If the switch has some control or management function, such as spanning tree or a management interface, those functons will have MAC addresses

Comment: You should add that MAC addresses need to be unique within each network (=L2 segment). UAA MAC addresses are even meant to be globally unique but that isn't always the case today.

Comment: @Zac67 You just did :)

Comment: @RonTrunk if interface a and interface always has unique ip address?

Comment: All interfaces **must** have unique addresses.  Every house has a unique street address.  Every cell phone has a unique telephone number.

Comment: @RonTrunk if router R1 has ip address 81.0.0.1/8 then interface a has unique address, then this should be 81.0.0.2,if suppose.?

Comment: @RonTrunk router ip and it's interface should be different?

Comment: Routers do not have IP addresses.  Their *interfaces* have IP addresses.  If a router has two interfaces, *each* interface has a unique address (on different subnets)

Comment: @RonTrunk if router R1 interface a has ip address 81.0.0.1/8 then it's routing table has information regarding 80.0.0.0/10 of router R2?

Comment: @RonTrunk interface a and b also unique Mac address?

Comment: Yes, every interface on the same L2 segment must have a unique MAC address, as Zac67 mentioned above

Comment: The routing table gets information in one of three ways:  1: The router knows its own interfaces.  2: You manually create a (static) route in the table. 3: You use a routing protocol to learn routes from other routers.

Comment: @RonTrunk in my 2nd image host  A wants to send frame  to switch at it respective interface N, then what would be destination Mac of A?

Comment: What is the destination?  Host B?

Comment: @RonTrunk destination is switch port N, then what is the host A  using destination Mac address?

Comment: @RonTrunk if the destination is B, then when frame forward to switch port N, what would be forwarded, since destination Mac address is host B?

Comment: Switches forward frames transparently - that means they don't change them.  [This question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13012/how-does-a-switch-learn-a-switch-table/13014#13014) may help you.

Comment: @RonTrunk when A sends frame then A reach to switch port N, by hosts A's port number M?I mean no need Mac address from to reach  to switch N?

Comment: If A is sending a frame for the switch itself, such as for management, then the switch has both an IP and mac address.  But when you send a frame to another host, the destination is the MAC address of that host.  Read the question I linked above.

Comment: @Rontrunk suppose router R1 has interface a has IP address 81.0.0.1 and IP address of interface b of R2 could be any belongs to any of 4 subnets. I mean interface b has IP address could be 80.0.0.1 or 80.64.0.2 or 80.128.0.2 or 80.192.0.5?

Comment: Interface a of R1 and interface b of R2 are on the same L2 segment.  Therefore they must have addresses in the same IP subnet.  Again, that subnet doesn't have to be part of 80.0.0.0.

Comment: @Rontrunk like IP address every router has distinct Mac address?

Comment: From the questions you're asking, it sounds like you don't really understand how two IP hosts communicate on a network.   For now, I suggest you forget about switches and routers, and just concentrate on how two IP hosts communicate.  You can imagine that they are connected by a simple cable.  You need to understand how both MAC and IP addresses are used.

Comment: Every Ethernet interface has a unique MAC address.  In theory, MACs are globally unique, but they only have to be unique on the L2 segment.

Comment: @Rontrunk if A connected by Ethernet to switch then both interface M and N has unique Mac address?

Comment: You keep asking the same question, and my answer is the same above. A switch port does not have a MAC address.

Comment: Switches are transparent. The host doesn’t know it’s there.

Comment: @Rontrunk router every interface has unique routing table?

Comment: No.  One routing table.